# Setting up GeoServer on GeoMesa HBase on AWS S3

Tags: geoserver, geomesa

I am running [GeoMesa Hbase on AWS S3](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/tutorials/geomesa-hbase-s3-on-aws.html). I am able to ingest / export data from inside the cluster with geomesa-hbase ingest / export but I am trying to acces the data remotely. I have installed GeoServer (on the same Master node where GeoMesa is running if that is relevant) but I have difficulty with providing GeoServer the correct JARs to acces GeoMesa. I can find the list of JARs that I should provide to GeoServer [here](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/hbase/install.html#install-hbase-geoserver) but I am not sure how or where to collect them. I have tried using the install-hadoop.sh & install-hbase.sh shell scripts in the /opt/geomesa/bin folder to install the HBase, Hadoop and Zookeeper JARs into GeoServers’ WEB-INF/lib folder, but if I change the Hadoop, Zookeeper & Hbase version in these shell scripts to be the same as the versions running on my cluster it does not find any JARS.

I am running everything on an EMR 6.2.0 release version (which comes with Hadoop 3.2.1, Hbase 2.2.6 and Zookeeper 3.4.14). On top of the cluster I am running GeoMesa 3.0.0-m0 with GeoServer 2.17 but I have also tried GeoMesa 2.4.0 with GeoServer 2.15. I’m fine with switching in either the EMR release version or GeoMesa/Server if that makes things easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, the setup that worked was:

- GeoMesa 3.1.1
- GeoServer 2.17.3
- Extract the geomesa-hbase-gs-plugin into GeoServer's WEB-INF/lib directory
- Run `install-dependencies.sh` (without modification) from the GeoMesa binary distribution to copy jars into GeoServer's WEB-INF/lib directory
- Copy the `hbase-site.xml` into GeoServer's WEB-INF/classes directory